# Auditing for User/Machine account logon/logoff events in Child Domain ONLY

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-event-log

I have searched high and low and cannot find an answer to my need. I am in the process of setting up a SIEM for our network and I need to audit for user and machine logon/logoff events. Simple enough except that our domain is a child domain in a forest with about 10 other domains. When I enable the necessary settings in the advanced audit policy configuration and set the appropriate entries in the SACL we are getting events for every logon/logoff event throughout the *entire AD forest*.

In short, is there any way to get ONLY the logon/logoff events to machines that are members of our child domain? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where are you configuring these settings?

Comment: domain controllers OU is where I've linked the GPO with the audit policy settings configured.